# Access Control Allow Origin Issue with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen several related issues about this on here but none has solved my problem yet.

I am trying to access the freckle(letsfreckle.com) api in a small web app I'm building but I'm having issues. It works when I start chrome browser without security but its not working on github pages and when I package the app as a chrome extension.

This is what my service looks like

```
 jXtnsion.factory('freckle', ['$http', function($http){
  return $http.get('https://api.letsfreckle.com/v2/projects?freckle_token=kacgnpf0og0hfi1it32o9xtc2ls2328-gmeb1nwcp1ko8o0f0ygi4mlxxxxxxxx&f&format=jsonp')
  .success(function(freckleData){
    return freckleData;
  })
  .error(function(err){
    return err;
  });
}]);
```

I keep getting a 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.letsfreckle.com/v2/projects?freckle_token=kacgnpf0og0hfi1it32o9xtc2ls2328-gmeb1nwcp1ko8o0f0ygi4mlxxxxxxxx&f&format=jsonp. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://andela-asogbein.github.io' is therefore not allowed access.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Does the API you're trying to call, allow cross-domain requests?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: You might need to register your API request before this will work for you. That is a server side deal it restricts people from accessing from other websites.

Comment: you are also request the `format=jsonp` - have you tries simply using `$http.jsonp`?

Comment: Have YOU appended service response with provided CORS Headers

Answer (score 0):

I think your server needs to correctly respond to the OPTIONS request that the browser will make on your behalf to determine if the CORS request is valid. It needs to contain an Access-Control-Allow-Headers header with the right info in it.

You can refer to this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by including

```
"permissions": [
"https://*/"
```

],

in my manifest.json file so it works without problem as a chrome extension. the problem seems to be from the freckle api as for the issue with local host